# Given $\kappa = \sup_{\alpha< \lambda} \kappa_{\alpha}$n can we assume the $\{\kappa_\alpha: \alpha < \lambda\}$ is strictly increasing?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

Suppose $$\kappa= \sup_{\alpha < \lambda} \kappa_\alpha$$
where $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal and $\kappa_\alpha$ are cardinals, $\lambda$ is a non-zero limit ordinal, $\lambda < \kappa$ and $\kappa_\alpha < \kappa$ for every $\alpha < \lambda$.

Does there exist a sequence $\{\kappa_\alpha': \alpha < \theta\}$ with $\kappa_\alpha' < \kappa, \theta < \kappa$, $\theta$ is a limit ordinal and $$\kappa = \sup_{\alpha < \theta} \kappa'_\alpha; \quad (\alpha < \beta \implies\kappa'_{\alpha}< \kappa'_\beta)$$

I saw the answers here: [Question on singular cardinals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280814/question-on-singular-cardinals/280822?noredirect=1#comment7637521_280822) but I was not able to understand them. If someone could give an explicit construction, I'd be glad:

My attempt: Using unions, one can make the sequence increasing, and then one wants to try to assume a subset that is strictly increasing but I'm not sure how to completely make this formal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Simply consider $\{\kappa_\alpha\mid\alpha<\lambda\}$ as a set of ordinals, it is a naturally well-ordered set. So we may simply consider its order type as $\theta$. Because $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal, this $\theta$ has to be a limit ordinal as well.

But we can do better. The set is isomorphic to an ordinal (by considering the order type of the set), so it has a cofinal sequence which is indexed by a *cardinal* which in turn has to be the cofinality of $\kappa$.

Comment: Sorry, but what I'm really looking for here is an explicit construction of the $\kappa'_\alpha$. I don't see something like that in your answer.

Comment: How do you make $\{0,2,5,3\}$ into an increasing sequence of natural numbers?

Comment: You take the smallest element, then the second smallest, then the third smallest, then the fourth smallest?

Comment: If your set is $X$, then $x_0 = \min X$, $x_1 = \min\{x \in X: x > x_0\}$ and so on.

Comment: Well, yes. And more reasonably, you simply order them using their natural well-ordering. When you see $\{0,1,2\}$ you are *already thinking about it in terms of an increasing sequence*. This applies to any set of ordinals.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm beginning to understand the answer. To clarify, your first paragraph already answers the question right?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: What I still don't get is why $\theta$ must be a limit ordinal? From what I understand, $\theta$ is the ordinal associated to the natural well-order on the set $\{\kappa_\alpha: \alpha < \lambda\}$ right?

Comment: Well, to be a successor type means to have a maximum. But since all the $\kappa_\alpha$ are strictly below $\kappa$, what could this maximum be?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe one last follow up question: intuitively this is clear, but is there a quick way to see $\lambda \geq \theta$?

Comment: For you this is probably very easy so forgive the easy question.

Comment: Well, $\theta$ is an order type of a set of size $\lambda$. So in general, it does not have to be less. But this is why I included the second paragraph. Once you use the fact that there is a cofinal subset, you're done.

Comment: But we are not given that $\lambda$ is a cardinal. The size would be $|\lambda|$, right?

Comment: When I say size $\lambda$, I mean, of course the same size *as* $\lambda$.

Comment: So from the first paragraph alone we don't have $\theta \leq \lambda?$

Comment: No, if we are not assuming that $\lambda$ is a cardinal, then you need to use the second paragraph as well.